# MYSQL Date year is saving in other format

Tags: java, mysql

I am using mysql with java. I need to insert date in database however its pretty easy in oracle but in Mysql I am facing bit weird problem. I am using java.sql.Date and when I am trying to insert 1990-08-21 it is saving in the form of 3912-01-21. I dont understand what I am missing.

```
    users.setDateOfBirth(new Date(1990-08-21));
```

Comment: Read the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html what you are saving is the result of 1990-8-21 = 1961

Comment: Did you mean to write commas instead of hyphens? EDIT: oh nvm that constructor is deprecated

Comment: Not in anyway related to Oracle/MySQL either.

Comment: `new Date(1990-08-21)` is not a correct way to create a new `Date` object. This will in fact not even compile, because `08` is not a valid octal number.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use java.util.Date instead of java.sql.Date. However java.util.date returns both date and time you can change into the format you wanted as in the above https://stackoverflow.com/a/42580378/7498469

Answer (score -1):

The expression `1990-08-21` is treated as 1990 - 8 - 21 = 1961.

The constructor for date expects a long integer (number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). So, its converted to that date (3912-01-21)

You need to use an different expression to convert a string date into a java Date:

```
users.setDateOfBirth(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("1990-08-21"));
```

For `java.sql.date`:

```
users.setDateOfBirth(new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("1990-08-21")));
```

You can use also a quick conversion (only for yyyy-mm-dd):

```
users.setDateOfBirth(java.sql.Date.valueOf("1990-08-21"));
```

Comment: this will return the java.util.Date